# Java use String value as Variable

Tags: java

I have a method with a Parameter Country. This Parameter only Contains an abbreviation of the Country. In the method i want to print the full name of the Country without switch case or something, but with predefined Strings

```
final String VA="Vatikan";
String country="VA";
system.out.println(country);
//Is it possible that it Prints Vatikan now?
//I know not with that code but is there a possibillity to do that.
```

Comment: I try to explain, I have a method with a Parameter Country. This Parameter only Contains an abbreviation of the Country. In the method i want to print the full name of the Country without switch case or something, but with predefined Strings

Comment: You're looking for a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: @user1877211 Please update your question with the clarification! It's quite a different question with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you could use a map to acheve the result you want.  Specifically, to return the full name of the abbreviated country name:

```
String va="Vatikan";
String country="VA";
Map<String, String> abbreviationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
abbreviationMap.put(country, va);
System.out.println(abbreviationMap.get(country)); //prints "Vatikan"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will assign it properly:

```
final String VA="Vatikan";
String country=VA;
System.out.println(country);
```

The String variable `country` will be pointed to whatever the variable `VA` is pointed to; because `VA` cannot change (it's `final`), country will point to "Vatikan".

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that assigning a `string "VA"` to country, but you want to treat it as a `variable`, so remove the `quotes("")`.

```
final String VA="Vatikan";
String country=VA;
System.out.println(country);
```